# How to register generic service with Autofac?

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac, mediatr, generic-type-argument, .net-4.7.2

I have a generic service:

```cs
public class FileDataService<T> : IFileDataService<T>
{
    public async Task<List<T>> GetListResultAsync(IFileSearcher<T> searcher)
    {
        return await searcher.GetResultsAsync();
    }
}
```

which I am trying to register:

```cs
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IFileDataService<>));
builder.RegisterType<SampleService>().As<ISampleService>();
builder.AddMediatR(this.GetType().Assembly);

builder.Register(c => UmbracoContext.Current).AsSelf();
```

to use it in dependency injection in `MediatR` handler;

```cs
public class QueryHandler : IRequestHandler<Query, Result>
{
    private readonly IFileDataService<ResultModel> _fileDataService;
    private readonly ISampleService _sampleService;
    private readonly UmbracoHelper _umbHelper;

    public QueryHandler(
        IFileDataService<ResultModel> fileDataService, ISampleService sampleService)
    {
        _fileDataService = fileDataService;
        _sampleService = sampleService;
        _umbHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
    }
```

It's telling me that the handler has not been properly constructed:

> Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler

How to properly register and use generic service in .NET 4.7.2 with `Autofac` & `MediatR`?

Comment: For this answer to be answerable, you will have to provide more information, such as a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and full exception details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is caused by the fact that `FileDataService<T>` is **not** a closed type, so `.AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IFileDataService<>));` won't pick it up.

What you want to do is register `FileDataService<T>` as a generic component, using the Autofac `RegisterGeneric` method; this cannot be done via the Assembly Scanning mechanism.

```cs
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(FileDataService<T>)).As(typeof(IFileDataService<>));
```

Docs: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components

Comment: Brilliant, that's what I was missing. Thank you!